# passing python strings, through cython, to C

Tags: python, c, cython

I am trying to write a module with some c and some python parts. I am using cython to bridge the gap.

I want to store my (very long) string constants in python, because of the much nicer syntax:

```c
const char long_string = "\npart of string\n"
  "next part\n"
  "last part\n";
```

versus:

```py
long_string = """
part of string
next part
last part
"""
```

(the strings are much longer than this, and more complicated - to the extent that I don't want to have to add and remove the `"`s and `\n"`s every time I want to edit it with syntax highlighting. In fact, they are openCL kernels.)

I need to be able to turn these into c strings using cython, and according to [the documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html) I should just need this:

```py
cdef bytes py_bytes = py_string.encode()
cdef char* c_string = py_bytes
```

and with no manual memory management, `c_string` will work as long as I keep a reference to `py_bytes`.

However, I can't get this working with a simple printf test. Here is my cython file:

```py
cdef extern from "stdio.h":
  printf(char* string)

def go():
  py_string = """
a complicated string
with a few
newlines.
"""

  cdef bytes py_bytes = py_string.encode()

  cdef char* c_string = py_bytes

  printf(c_string)

  print "we don't get this far :("
```

which, when compiled at runtime using `pyximport` gives the following output to terminal before segfaulting:

```
a complicated string
with a few
newlines.
Segmentation fault: 11
```

now, I've checked what cython actually puts in the c file, and tried it in a vanilla C file where it **doesn't** segfault:

```c
#include "stdio.h"

static char __pyx_k_1[] = "\na complicated string\nwith a few\nnewlines.\n";

int main(void) {
  void* output = printf(__pyx_k_1);
  if (!output) {
    printf("apparently, !output.");
  }
}
```

to be clear, cython generates code which catches the output of `printf` and tests for "not that". the type of the variable is a `PyObject*`.

My only guess here was that the string was improperly terminated, so printf just carries on past the end of it and causes the segfault, but since that doesn't happen in my pure c test, I'm completely stumped.

So, my actual question is how do I *really* pass a c-string to c code from cython? Answers pointing out an easier way to solve the actual problem I'm trying to solve at the top are also very welcome :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Importing `printf` from `libc.stdio` fixes the problem for me:

```
from libc.stdio cimport printf

def go():
    py_string = """
a complicated string
with a few
newlines.
"""

    cdef bytes py_bytes = py_string.encode()
    cdef char* c_string = py_bytes
    printf(c_string)

    print "we actually got this far! :)"
```

The error is in the declaration of `printf`. That should have been, as `stdio.pxd` lists,

```
cdef extern from *:
    ctypedef char const_char "const char"

int printf(const_char *, ...)
```

whereas your version is implicitly `object printf(char *)`; the default return value type is Python object rather than `int` as in C. Getting the right declaration turns off Cython's attempt to `Py_XDECREF` the return value from `printf`.

(Btw, in your "vanilla" C problem, you shouldn't be casting the return value from `printf` to `void *`.)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem immediately. I had clearly misunderstood `cimport` - I thought you had to specify the types exactly.

Comment: @tehwalrus: you didn't specify the type exactly. It should have been `int printf(const_char *, ...)` where you have to `ctypedef char const_char "const char"` manually. I think Cython presumes a return type of `object` rather than `int`.

Comment: @tehwalrus: in fact, I checked the generated code again and this is exactly what went wrong. See updated answer for an explanation of the error.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I will be more careful in my definitions in future! :)